# python parallel paralle process - joblib for nested loops - track original indices for the input

Tags: python, indexing, parallel-processing, joblib

I was using joblib for parallel processing a list (>500k rows) to find out duplicates in the file. Therefore, I needed to track indices of the input list. However, the result returned indices in each thread/processing and they were not originally indices in the list (range 0-500k+). How can I track the original indices of the input in the parallel processing? Thank you.

```
import time
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

start_time = time.time()
texts = a_list

def match_name(texts):
    result = []

    for i, text in enumerate(texts):
       for j, name in enumerate(texts[i+1:]):
            fratio = fuzz.token_set_ratio(text, name)
            if fratio>=75:
                result.append([i,j, fratio])
    return result

 results2 = Parallel(n_jobs=200, verbose=5, backend="loky")(map(delayed(match_name), texts))

 print(time.time() - start_time)
```

The actual result is:

```
[[[1, 1, 100],
  [1, 4, 100],
  [1, 6, 100],
  [2, 2, 100],
  [2, 4, 100],
  [3, 2, 100],
  [3, 4, 100],
  [5, 1, 100],
  [6, 1, 100]],
 [[0, 14, 100],
  [1, 6, 100],
  [1, 14, 100],
  [2, 9, 100],
  [2, 14, 100],
  [8, 7, 100],
  [9, 0, 100],
  [9, 12, 100],
  [10, 11, 100],
  [12, 4, 100],
  [13, 9, 100]],
 [[1, 24, 100],
  [3, 21, 100],
  [5, 7, 100],
  [6, 17, 100],
  [9, 1, 100],
  [9, 9, 100],
  [11, 7, 100],
  [12, 2, 100],
  [17, 4, 100]],
 [[0, 18, 100],
  [0, 19, 100],
  [2, 5, 100],
 ...]
```

The expected result ranges 0 to 500k+, which is the length of the list.

Comment: Thats a bit off topic, but since you care about performance I would replace your usage of FuzzyWuzzy with RapidFuzz (I am the author), which provides the same string metric, but uses a faster implementation: https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/fuzz.html#token-set-ratio

Comment: Thank you for the note, @maxbachmann. I will definitely try it out.